# make keeps rearranging the arguments in the rule command - how do I stop that?

Tags: makefile, autotools

witihn the target, there is a rule that invokes libtool with some arguments. Actual command line that gets executed when rule triggers has arguments rearranged.

I tried rearranging the argument sequence in a rule in various combinations, but final line that is executed, is always the same.

Finally, I tried capturing all the line that shall be executed in one variable and then entered that variable to be expanded as a line that gets executed by the shell. That works.

E.g:

1 - original, that fails:

```
target.o:
<--------->$(some_command) $(first_arg) $(second_one) $(third) $(fourth)
```

On triggering the rule, something like this gets executed

```
<--------->$(some_command)  $(second_one) $(fourth) $(third)  $(first_arg)
```

WTF?

In case it's relevant, that some_command is libtool.

(this is from Makefile | gsymcheck/src/MAkefile | within gEDA CAD, that I'm trying to mend to be compilable with LTO  optimizations BTW.)

line is:

```
$(AM_V_CCLD)$(gsymcheck_LINK) $(gsymcheck_OBJECTS) $(gsymcheck_LDADD) $(LIBS)
```

expect for the recept line of the rule to be executed as it was given, without make playing "origami" with it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There appears to be a space missing between `$(AM_V_CCLD)` and `$(gsymcheck_LINK)`; is that correct?

Comment: @9769953: Yes. But that part seems to be OK. $(AM_V_CLD) expands to empty string. $(gsymckeck_LINK) expands to that libtool command sequence. $(gsymcheck_LDADD) expands to internal library name ../../libgeda/src/libgeda.la

Comment: @9769953:      Interstingly, libgeda.la gets converted to libgeda.so when executed ( in reality, existing .la file is referencing .so).     Also, no matter how I position $(gsymcheck_LDADD), it always ends up being in front of $(LIBS)...

Comment: There is no way for us to help with the information provided.  At the _very least_ we need to see the actual recipe as it appears in the makefile, rather than things like `$(first_arg) $(second one)` etc.  From that we _might_ be able to guess what the problem is.  As melpomene says, a full example would allow us to avoid guessing.

Comment: I do not believe for a moment that *`make`* is rearranging anything.  But you mentioned `libtool`, and I could believe that `libtool` executes commands in which the options are reordered relative to the order of the corresponding options presented to it by `make`.

Comment: In any case, yours seems to be an Automake-based makefile.  In that case, it is a *generated* file, and the Automake `Makefile.am` and / or Autoconf `configure.ac` is where you should be trying to apply changes.

Comment: @John Bolliinger: I don't see hwo the libtool could rearrange the make-generate output line, showing what it is executing. WRT to AM stuff, I did try that, with little success. In the end, it appeared that my problem, looking on the short run, could be solved in different way - by specifying an option to the linke rhat allows for dynamic library to be used without being itself fully resolved. But I plan to return to the broedare picture later - I have to know whate went wrong there...

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, @Brane212.  `make` executes a `libtool` command, which it by default also echoes to its output.  I refuse to believe that this is reordered in any way relative to its variable-expanded appearance in the makefile.  `libtool` then chooses, prints, and executes either one or two compilation or link commands, which typically include many of the options it itself received -- it is *these* that I am prepared to believe have a different option order than you expect.